# Windows 10 runs applications that are not configured for auto-start

Tags: windows-10, autostart

Since I installed the Windows 10 Fall Creators update I experience a changed startup behavior. Windows runs applications that are not configured with autostart (Task Manager > Startup) on startup, and I don´t like that (for instance Visual Studio, or Office applications that I use frequently). Does anybody know how I can disable that behavior?

Comment: Are these programs open when you shut the computer down/restart it?

Comment: @music2myear Maybe processes have not been finally terminated, but the main application windows are usually closed already... anyway, I do not expect those apps to get started automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a function of Cortana, added after the most recent update (Fall Creator's Update, build 1709).

To disable it, open the Start Menu and begin typing something (or just click the magnifying glass icon on your taskbar).

In the search window, select to Allow Cortana to Personalize the Experience, then you can toggle "Pick Up Where I Left Off" off.

Comment: Cortana seems to be disabled on my machine... the search box is hidden, but if I start typing after pressing the Win-key, nothing is found when I search for "Pick up where...".

Comment: Is this computer on a domain?

Comment: No, it´s a standalone desktop.

Comment: Did you disable Cortana?

Comment: Hm, seems so... how can I check that? Cortana seems to be absent at all.

Comment: Well, Cortana doesn't typically disappear by itself, but many Windows 10 Cleanup and Optimization utilities tend to enjoy disabling it, and only you'll know if you've run one of those.

Comment: Nope, I don´t... I usually tend to stick with default settings and tools, to avoid such issues; but Cortana is something that I don´t want to use, so I guess I disabled it, but can´t remember when and how (-: